# Why does splitting an mp4 file with ffmpeg leave silence at the beginning and end?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to split an mp4 file into smaller chunks, but each chunk seems to have a tiny bit of silence at the beginning and end of it.  Is there some way I can split an mp4 file without all this silence?

I'm doing something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i raw.mp4 -ss 2.234 -to 8.641 slice.mp4 -y
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you viewing the output?

Comment: Audacity. I can see flatness.

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/25297/

Comment: Even when I open it with Celluloid, I can hear the gaps.  Even if I merge the slices back together with ffmpeg, I can still hear the gaps.